# Get JSON into select box and display an answer with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, html-select

I have a huge JSON file, and each object has three attributes:

```
[
    {
        "Product": "Hurtta Frost Jacket",
        "Dog Type": "Affenpinscher",
        "Size for the dog": "25, 30"
    },
    {
        "Product": "Hurtta Frost Jacket",
        "Dog Type": "Afghan Hound",
        "Size for the dog": "60, 65"
    }
]
```

A Product a Dog Type and a Size for the dog.

What I need is to make to select boxes one for the Product and one for the Dog Type, and when these two options are selected the size for the dog for that object will display in a div anywhere. What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why 2 "select boxes": each product has a single corresponding dog type in your example. And the coma in the size, does it mean it's 2 different sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="product"><option value="">Select Product</option></select>
<select id="type"><option value="">Select Dog Type</select></select>
<br>Size:
<div id="size"></div>

$(function () {
    json_obj = [{
        "Product": "Hurtta Frost Jacket",
            "Dog Type": "Affenpinscher",
            "Size for the dog": "25, 30"
    }, {
        "Product": "Hurtta Frost Jacket",
            "Dog Type": "Afghan Hound",
            "Size for the dog": "60, 65"
    }];
    var products_added = {};
    var types_added = {};
    $.each(json_obj, function () {
        if (!products_added[this.Product]) {
            $("#product").append($("<option/>", {
                value: this.Product,
                text: this.Product
            }));
            products_added[this.Product] = true;
        }
        if (!types_added[this["Dog Type"]]) {
            $("#type").append($("<option/>", {
                value: this["Dog Type"],
                text: this["Dog Type"]
            }));
            types_added[this["Dog Type"]] = true;
        }
    });

    $("#product, #type").change(function () {
        $("#size").empty();
        var product = $("#product").val();
        var type = $("#type").val();
        if (product && type) {
            $.each(json_obj, function () {
                if (product == this.Product && type == this["Dog Type"]) {
                    $("#size").text(this["Size for the dog"]);
                    return false; // terminate the loop
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Xecd2/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am getting a syntax err on the line that starts $("#product, #type").change(){

Comment: Fixed, I was missing a close parenthesis on the previous line

Comment: It has something to do with  .change(){}

Comment: I added .change(function(){})

Comment: So, I fixed the syntax errors, and the option boxes are displaying nicely, but the #size dive text doesn't change

Comment: Wow, could I pay you to help me on skype?

Comment: I recommend using simpler names for your object properties, so you don't have to use verbose syntax like `this["Size for the dog"]`.